# Cannot execute kotlin coroutine (no such method exception

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I took this simple code snippet from kotlin examples:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking<Unit> {
    withTimeout(1300L) {
        repeat(1000) { i ->
            println("I'm sleeping $i ...")
            delay(500L)
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run it, it throws

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.ScheduledKt.withTimeout$default(JLjava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function2;ILjava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

I use **kotlinVersion = '1.1.51'**

Any advice?

Comment: Are you compiling with one version of the library, and running with a different one?

Comment: This is a compiler bug. Please file an issue to http://kotl.in/issue

Comment: @RomanElizarov nope, apparently it's not compiler bug bud Idea 15.0.3 defect, when I test the code with *gradle test* it fails as expected with *TimeoutCancellationException*, otherwise (in IntelliJ) i get NSM exception.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, make sure that in your build.gradle file you enable coroutines :

```
kotlin {
    experimental {
        coroutines "enable"
    }
}
```

Also you should trigger your coroutine with launch(UI) and call explicitly wait() and the suspended methods. The rest of your code will be executed on the UI thread.

Hope it resolved your issue!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, my gradle conf contains mentioned declaration (use experimental coroutines). Regarding launch, I thought withTimeout is a direct replacement of launch (with additional time frame for execution). BTW, there's no UI code, I have just single kotlin script file with one method. Does it mean that kotlin examples are incomplete and some extra code is required?

Comment: *EDIT*: one more thing, indeed, when I switch from withTimeout to launch it works, nonetheless, I'm more interested in time-out functionality.

Comment: sure, I will, but your answer has not helped to solve my problem yet.